# Can we bring two ec2 instances under one active directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, active-directory, windows-server-2008, dynamics-crm

I am trying to communicate between two ec2 instances which are having windows server 2008 installed. On one of the server I have installed Active directory and I want to bring another ec2 instance under one active directory.

I'm new to Amazon with active directory.

The problem I am trying to address is Installing dynamics CRM on these two ec2 instances. From  my assumption or understanding, CRM requires a CRM web server and SQL server under 1 Active directory.

Any comments with links or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory relies on DNS, so it all depends how you setup DNS for your instances.

But in summary if instance `A` is the domain controller for my.domain.com and instance `B` wants to join the domain then you have to make sure that  instance `B` can get to instance `A` by resolving my.domain.com to the right IP address of `A`.

When you create an Active Directory domain controller, the controller itself automatically becomes a DNS server so the easiest way is just to make the default DNS server for instance `B` the actual IP address of instance `A` (you should be able to use the internal Amazon IP address as long as it's pingable)

Hope this helps.